# "To ..." as a subject of a sentence?

Tags: inversion

> To the Mall’s polite formality--   its “tulips all in a line,” in House’s words-- has come a contrasting presence: a wetland visible from the Capitol sprouting cattails, wild rice and about 1,440 waterlilies.  (From ACT)

I simplify the sentence as following:

> To the Mall’s polite formality has come a presence.

I don't understand the subject of this sentence, "to the Mall's polite formality"?

Comment: A presence has come to the Mall’s polite formality.

Comment: It might work in some poetic context, but generally speaking, utterances like *To the Mall’s polite formality has come a presence* aren't remotely idiomatic in English. Just stick to Subject-Verb-Object: *A presence has come to the Mall’s polite formality.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though less common than subject | predicate, the [order may be inverted](https://www.thoughtco.com/inversion-definition-1209968). This is used, for example, to make a point more clear or to ask a question.

```
So cold was it that words froze out of the air.
He is happy. [statement] => Is he happy? [question]
```

Comment: Your simplification is correct, @Charlie. "To" simply marks the indirect object: the Mall's formality. In "John came to London", "John" is the subject and "London" is the indirect object. The subject of your sentence is the contrasting presence of the wetland. It has come to the Mall.)